# trying to insert directive into ui accordion body but gets converted to text

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-bootstrap

From the docs of angular bootstrap accordion I am trying to insert html into the accordion body.

```
$scope.groups = [
  {
    title: 'Dynamic Group Header - 1',
    content: '<h1>Dynamic Group Body - 1</h1>'
  },
  {
    title: 'Dynamic Group Header - 2',
    content: 'Dynamic Group Body - 2'
  }
];
```

However this converts it to text and does not give me the html. Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Wait did you mean directive or just an html. I dont see any directive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly bind html using angular binding, they will be rendered as text. They need to be sanitized. So try:-

In your accordion bind the content with [`ng-bind-html`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml):-

```
     <accordion-group heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">
      <div ng-bind-html="group.content"></div>
    </accordion-group>
```

and also include ng-sanitize to your module dependencies, after including the script.

Example:-

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngSanitize']);
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/cHDVaX?p=preview)**